# Tweedie p parameter Interpretation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, tweedie-distribution, frequency-severity

From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution) we know that

> The Tweedie distributions include a number of familiar distributions as well as some unusual ones, each being specified by the domain of the index parameter. We have the
> normal distribution, p = 0,
> Poisson distribution, p = 1,
> compound Poisson–gamma distribution, 1 < p < 2,
> gamma distribution, p = 2,
> positive stable distributions, 2 < p < 3,
> inverse Gaussian distribution, p = 3,
> positive stable distributions, p > 3, and
> extreme stable distributions, p = ∞.
>
> For 0 < p < 1 no Tweedie model exists.

My question is can we determine significance from the optimal $p$ if it is between 1-2.  For instance, if we say that Poisson controls the frequency in which our $Y$ appears and Gamma controls the size of our $Y$ if it appears and if the log-likelihood of the model has an optimal value for $p$ of 1.1 then is it fair to say that the data is driven more by frequency than size and *vice versa*?

So for example, if you run this code:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- rep(1:100, times=10)
freq <- sapply(x,function(arg) rpois(1,.25*arg))
size <- sapply(x,function(arg) rgamma(1,100*arg))
y <- freq*size
df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

tweediep <- tweedie.profile(y ~ x, link.power = 0, data = df, 
    do.smooth = FALSE, do.plot = TRUE)
tweediep$xi.max
```

I get the result 1.3.  Does that mean that this Y is more "driven by" frequency than severity?  Does it mean something else altogether?  Is there nothing I can discern from this estimated value of the parameter $p$ ?

Edit:  This is not a complete answer so I'm posting it as an edit and clarification rather than an answer to my own question.

I have attempted to anecdotally answer my own question via a limited experiment.  Specifically, I want to create dummy data and a "frequency driven" and "severity driven" model from this data and observe the results to better understand the $p$ parameter.

```r
set.seed(1)

# creating random variables
x1 <- rep(1:5,20)
x2 <- (runif(100))*10
x3 <- rpois(100,5)
x4 <- rweibull(100,2,5)

# creating parameters based off a linear combination of variables plus 
#  a noise term - all exponentiated    

fvars <- exp((x1+2*x2+.5*x3-x4+3*runif(1))/10)/5
svars <- exp((x1+2*x2+.5*x3-x4+3*runif(1))/5)
summary(fvars)
summary(svars)

# freq is the number of occurrences, sev is the size of the 
# occurrences
freq <- rpois(100, fvars)
sev <- rgamma(100, scale=svars, shape=1)

summary(freq)
summary(sev)

results1 <- freq*sev
summary(results1)

# load library if needed
library(tweedie)

# store all the data in a single data frame
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, results1))
```

This is my "base model".  I now find the optimal parameter $p$.

```r
tweediep <- tweedie.profile(formula = results1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + 
             x4,link.power = 0, do.smooth = TRUE, do.plot = TRUE)
tweediep$xi.max
```

I get a result of 1.616327 .  I went ahead and found the results model coefficients.  Strictly for the purposes of answering my question, I don't believe actually fitting the glm is necessary but perhaps the diagnostics of the glm will lead to more insight.

```r
baseGLM <- glm(results1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data=df1, 
               family=tweedie(var.power = tweediep$xi.max, 
               link.power = 0))
summary(baseGLM)
```

It's possible that the model isn't "fit well enough" for this type of analysis to say anything meaningful, but to continue this line of reasoning, let's try fitting a "frequency driven model".

```r
# freq driven

freq <- rpois(100, fvars*3)
sev <- rgamma(100, scale=svars/4, shape=1)

summary(freq)
summary(sev)

results2 <- freq*sev
summary(results2)

df1 <- data.frame(cbind(df1, results2))

tweediep2 <- tweedie.profile(formula = results2~x1+x2+x3+x4, 
               link.power = 0, do.smooth = TRUE, do.plot = TRUE)
tweediep2$xi.max
```

here our $p$ parameter value is 1.718367 which is higher than our base value.  Again, we fit the model.

```r
GLMfreqDriven <- glm(results2 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data=df1, 
    family=tweedie(var.power = tweediep2$xi.max, link.power = 0))
summary(GLMfreqDriven)
```

Finally, let's make our model more severity driven.

```r
# severity driven

freq <- rpois(100, fvars*.4)
sev <- rgamma(100, scale=svars*5, shape=1)

summary(freq)
summary(sev)

results3 <- freq*sev
summary(results3)

df1 <- data.frame(cbind(df1, results3))

tweediep3 <- tweedie.profile(formula = results3 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + 
               x4,link.power = 0, do.smooth = TRUE, do.plot = TRUE)
tweediep3$xi.max
```

Here our $p$ parameter is 1.591937.

This is the opposite of my initial hypothesis.  I originally thought that the more frequency driven a model is, the closer the `p` parameter would be to 1 (since 1 is a true Poisson model), and the more severity driven the model is, closer the `p` parameter is to 2.  In my, admittedly limited, experiment the opposite was true.  The Poisson distribution does allow zeros as a response variable.  Perhaps the `p` parameter has nothing to do with "frequency driven" or "severity driven", but is strictly a function of the number of zeros in the data (for `p` parameter values between 1 and 2).

One possible limitation I thought of with respect to my experiment design is that would be interesting to see how the results change if I force the `results1`, `results2`, and `results3` variables to all have the same mean.  The data here was fit arbitrarily.  Several of instances where I am dividing or multiplying by a constant, I am doing so to get the data in such a way that the algorithm converges without error.  I would be more confident if the results (1.61, 1.72, 1.59) were more spread out.

In conclusion, I can see possible explanations for results of my limited experiment, but would really be appreciative if someone could further validate and explain how the $p$ parameter is affected by the data.  Any discussion as to the differences between creating separate frequency and severity models versus creating compound Poisson-gamma models may also prove to be very insightful.

Answer (score 3):

The *Generalized Linear Models with Examples in R* book by Peter Dunn and Gordon Smyth contains an illuminating discussion of Tweedie distributions.

If I maybe so blunt, and summarize your excellent question:

What is the relation of $p$ and the underlying Poisson-Gamma model for a Tweedie distribution with $1 < p < 2$?

As you already note in your question, the Tweedie distribution with $1 < p < 2$ can be understood as a Poisson-Gamma model. To make it more concrete what this means, let's assume that

$$
N \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda^{*})
$$
and
$$
z_i \sim \text{Gam}(\mu^{*}, \phi^{*})
$$
the observed $y$ is
$$
y = \sum_{i = 1}^{N}{z_i}.
$$
Dunn & Smyth give an example for this model, where $N$ is the number of insurance claims and $z_i$ is the average cost for each claim. In that case the model would describe the total insurance payout.

The relation of $p$ to the parameters of the Poisson and Gamma distribution is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lambda^{*} &= \frac{\mu^{2-p}}{\phi (2-p)} \\
\mu^{*} &= (2 - p)\phi\mu^{p - 1} \\
\phi^{*} &= (2 - p)(p - 1) \phi^2\mu^{2(p - 1)}, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ and $\phi$ are the mean and overdispersion parameters from the generalized linear model definition.